# How does one implement the typedef hack in an antlr4 grammar

Tags: macros, alias, antlr4, typedef, keyword

I don't need typedef's exactly.  I need aliases (for a shell language).  But the hack of looking up an identifier and returning a different token type is what I need to make the grammar work.  I don't necessarily need it to be done in the lexer, although that would seem cleanest to me (or in a phase between the lexer and parser).

Here is (a fragment of) the closest I can seem to come to a solution given what I know of antlr4, but it requires a whole level of non-terminals for each keyword token.  Note, that per Antlr4 Capitalized words or tokens, lower case words are non-terminals.

```
  aliasstmt: alias ident ident; // rule that makes aliases
  ifstmt: if expression then statement;  // sample rule with two keywords

  // non-terminals converting aliases into keywords
  alias: Alias // normal token for keyword
       // hack, LookupAlias is map, I need. 
       | { LookupAlias(_input.LT(1).getText()).equals("alias") }? Ident 
       ;
  if   : If
       | { LookupAlias(_input.LT(1).getText()).equals("if") }? Ident 
       ;
  then : Then
       | { LookupAlias(_input.LT(1).getText()).equals("then") }? Ident 
       ;

  // Non-terminal going the other way, converting keywords to identifiers when needed
  ident : Ident
        | Alias
        | If
        | Then
        ;
```

Now, I suppose, I could get rid of the Tokens for the keywords and do it all in the parser for this example.  It wouldn't completely work in the language I'm parsing because a significant number of the keywords have "normal" spellings like "Set-Alias" or "-Name" which are not legal identifiers (and "Set - Alias" or "Set -Alias" is not the same as "Set-Alias", uggh).

However, I want to LookupAlias() function to be it's own Java class not something just embedded in the parser.  I have other times I need to us it that aren't part of parsing and those times need to have then coordinated.  How to do that is a separate question I will ask.

Comment: Your title says “typedef hack”, but reading the question it appears that you want to actually be able to alias keywords in your language.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the actual functionality, but in particular, I need the user of the language to be able to dynamically do that, so it needs to be a "lookup" function that checks some kind of symbol table (database) to see what aliases the user has specified as part of their program.

Comment: Fortunately, I don't need to implement a macro preprocessor so far.  Although, if I have this, I know how to leverage it to do so.

Comment: The "builtin" (predefined) aliases were easy to do.  It's the dynamic user defined ones that are giving me grief.

Answer (score 1):

(Caveat... maybe aliases can be used in a shell in places I don’t know about, so this is based on my understanding)

In a shell, an alias is essentially an identifier that is expanded when it’s encountered.  It’s only expected where a `command` could occur, and since you can’t know all the command in the path, your grammar would likely have an `IDENTIFIER` token (or the like) at that location in the parser rule.

You’d then check it against a list of built-in commands, commands in your PATH, and aliases (I’m not sure of the precedence, TBH).

So, you’d need to keep a symbol table to look up the alias resolution.  I think post-resolution is where things will get “tricky”.  IIRC, aliases don’t have to be syntactically complete, you you couldn’t really expect to pre-parse them (they possibly won’t parse correctly). Also, they are pretty much “injected” into the input stream.  In this way they’re much more like pre-processor macros.  I don’t see much way around detecting them, building an expanded input stream and lexing/parsing it.

I suppose that you could write a custom TokenStream, that detected aliases and responded to getNextToken() (and methods to get the token at a particular index, etc.).  That would allow aliases anywhere in the token stream, which could get weird, and it would be the devil, probably, to provide useful error messages.  (I guess you’d just have to point them at the alias itself).  This approach would supply the alias definition tokens in place of the alias as the parser asked for the next token.  I don’t see a way that you’ll use actions/predicates to change ANTLRs mind about what token it just saw :).

I suspect playing with existing shells a bit, creating invalid alias substitutions into the command line, and observing the error messages, might give insight into how other shells handle it.  My impression, is that the shell preprocess the input and substitutes things like aliases and ENV variables, etc. and then re-parses the result the result for execution.

I’m pretty sure trying to modify the tokenStream as the parser is already processing it, is either no doable, or the path to madness.

Comment: Thanks, for the TokenStream pointer.  That gives me a single point of responsibility for dealing with it.  Yes, I'm currently dealing with aliases by a "catchall" rule at the end of the precedence (so that I know if I get to it, I would be generating a syntax error otherwise) that uses IDENT followed by just about anything and then does the lookup and reparses with the text with the replacement inserted.  But, it isn't the solution I would be using with Yacc++, where integrating the lookup into the lexer is easy and part of the lexer specification.

Comment: I had the "reparse" solution already in place for the equivalent to the "eval" command which takes a string and then "executes" it, so I had already worked out how to build the steps to build a new lexer/parser/token stream/etc objects based on the character string, but keep the same execution context (i.e. runtime stack) the same.

Comment: And eventually, I will need "macros" and they will have to reparse.  But, this was a case, where I would have liked to have added "types" to the grammar, not every IDENT is an alias (but you don't know which ones are or are not until run-time) and I would like to only invoke the reparsing if it is.